# How would I calculate the gravity on the surface of a large rectangular solid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, estimation

[This story on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HFY/comments/cp9otp/the_very_large_blunt_object_ancients/) involves a 1 km by 1 km by 1.79 lightyear block of lead in deep space, and I was wondering if it was at all feasible (though that question is probably out of scope). To ask a more answerable question, how would I determine the surface gravity of such an object? In particular, how much gravity would you experience if you were standing in the middle of one of the two square sides?

Comment: What is your definition of "how much gravity"?

Comment: @AaronStevens "how much gravity" = how much acceleration due to gravity would you experience

Comment: FWIW, lead's pretty soft, and gravity will tend to convert the block to a sphere, with a radius a shade over 15930 km, assuming I didn't mess up the arithmetic (I used Google Calculator).

Comment: @PM2Ring yes lead is soft, but consider a 1 mm by 1 mm version - all that put together into a sphere would give 0.005 m/s^2 surface gravity, but spread out over more than a lightyear? The gravitational pull seems like it would be negligible, allowing it to remain a rectangular prism. If you made it bigger at some point it would obviously pull itself together into a sphere, but where is that point? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium#Planetary_geology suggests for spheres it's around 400 km for ice and somewhat more than that for rock.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3857

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the gravity of *any* distribution of mass by doing an integral, perhaps numerically?

Comment: @G.Smith I tried to, but the answer I got didn't make sense. So I'm pretty sure I messed up somewhere, but I'm not sure where.